# Javascript code not working in Mobiles

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

I have a javascript code which restricts users from entering Special Characters, Blank space and more.

The function works well on the desktop, but in mobile, it is not working.

My Code:

```
<script> 
$(function() {     
var haveFirst = false;
$('.alphaonly').on('keypress', function (event) {
  if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
     haveFirst = false;
  }
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_]+$");
var first = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if(!first.test(key) && haveFirst == false){
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}else if(regex.test(key)){
   haveFirst = true;
}
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
}); 
})  
</script>
```

Comment: keypress event is not available on most mobile platforms, try to use input

Comment: @mr.void how should I use `input`? What changes should I do in `$('.alphaonly').on('keypress', function (event) {`?

Comment: @Coder whats about event.target?

Comment: replace keypress with, input

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze I did not understand

Comment: @mr.void I tried `$('.alphaonly').on('input', function (event) {`, but it is not restricting also.

Comment: @IndianCoder - try replacing keypress with touchstart ?

Comment: @Always_hungry how should I use `touchstart`? What changes should I do in `$('.alphaonly').on('keypress', function (event) {`?

Comment: $('.alphaonly').on('touchstart', function (event)

Comment: @Always_hungry tried. but it is not restricting also.